# Local Binary Patterns features using matlab 'extractLBPFeatures'

Tags: matlab, feature-extraction, pattern-recognition, lbph-algorithm

I am trying to understand the `extractLBPFeatures` function to extract the 59 uniform features, here is a simple code that extracts the 59 features from an image

```
img = imread('cameraman.tif');
LBP = extractLBPFeatures(img, 'Normalization' , 'none');
```

From what I understand according to [LBP and Uniform LBP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns) , the LBP is like histogram that counts the frequency of the pixels, but instead of intensity, the binary code of each centre pixel (converted into a new digit),  so we would get bins from 0 to 59 with a number of occurrences of that each digit

Here are the LBP features, but shouldn't the numbers be real numbers since it is counting the frequency or occurrences of each pixel?
[image]

Comment: Please don't post code or data as images.

Comment: Those are real numbers. However, it's a histogram, it should report counts, so I would expect integers in it, and those numbers are not integers. Not sure what computation they're doing there.